# view db from eclipse

Tags: sql, eclipse, viewer, records

I am trying to find a solution to check the database records from the Eclipse itself.Nothing fancy is needed except one click on table name and all the records appear to check if my recent query did what I was expected. I have admin UI for postgreSQL, but I would want to see the data from within IDE. There is/was a tool which partially fulfilled the idea however it seems that development is in dead end in there, to see the data you actually need to write queries which is waste of time when you just want to view the data as result from previous query.

The native postgresql UI itself is fine, but then these tons of opened windows do irritate increasing visual search time.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Quantum](http://quantum.sourceforge.net/index.html) (which I haven't tried yet) or [SQL Explorer](http://www.sqlexplorer.org/index.php).
Good luck